# calling tableView reloadData on a table that's embedded in a containerView contained within a UIView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7, reloaddata, uicontainerview

I tried doing this in LogFrameViewController to get a hold of the table view:

```
FrameSettingsTableViewController *FrameSettingsTableViewController = [[FrameSettingsTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FrameSettingsTableViewController" bundle:nil];
[[FrameSettingsTableViewController frameSettingsTableView] reloadData];
```

I was able to set some other properties in FrameSettingsTableViewController but can't reload the data, setting a breakpoint shows the table view to be nil.

How do I go about getting a reference to that table view from within my LogFrameViewController in order to reloadData?

[image: here's my storyboard]

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to rename your variable to something that is not the class name

```
FrameSettingsTableViewController *frameSettingsTableViewController = [[FrameSettingsTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FrameSettingsTableViewController" bundle:nil];
[[frameSettingsTableViewController frameSettingsTableView] reloadData];
```

Note the lower-case 'f' in frameSettingsTableViewController

Comment: Na, that's not it. My classnames are prefixed, just removed them here for clarity.